# Show a function $F$ is quasi-concave

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

Show that a function $F$ is quasi-concave if $h(x) = g(F(x))$ is a concave function for some strictly increasing function g from R to R.

I already know that if $h$ is concave, then $h$ must be quasi-concave, but given that $h$ being a monotone transformation of function $F$ is concave (also quasi-concave), how to prove that $F$ must also be quasi-concave?

Note that the a function is quasi-concave if for any $x_0$ and $x_1$ and any convex combination $x_\lambda$, if $f(x_1)\ge f(x_0)$ then $f(x_\lambda)\ge f(x_0)$.

Comment: $g$ is invertible on its range.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a formal proof without using the invertible property of $g$.

Comment: I think you must use the injective nature of $g$, otherwise the result is not true.

Comment: Use chain rule. Then, we can know that if h is concave, 
(i) then g is concave and non-decreasing, and F is concave, or
(ii) g is concave and non-increasing, F is convex. 
Here, g is non-decreasing, so F is concave and hence Quasi-concave.